# Node.js + Express routes not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am semi-new to Node.js and I'm having some confusion with connecting to my local host and interfacing with MongoDB. It seems as though it is ignoring my routes I have created.

First off, here is a snapshot of my directory structure.

[image]

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "summer_breeze",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./start.js"
  },
  "author": "*** ********",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mongod": "^2.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.7",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.1",
    "normalize.css": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here is my start.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// import environmental variables from our variables.env file
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variables.env' });

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, { useMongoClient: true });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; 
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`${err.message}`);
});


const app = require('./app');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7777);
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

Here is my app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const routes = require('./routes/index');
const errorHandlers = require('./handlers/errorHandlers');


const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.use('/', routes);

// If that above routes didnt work, we 404 them and forward to error handler
app.use(errorHandlers.notFound);

// One of our error handlers will see if these errors are just validation errors
app.use(errorHandlers.flashValidationErrors);

// Otherwise this was a really bad error we didn't expect! Shoot eh
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  /* Development Error Handler - Prints stack trace */
  app.use(errorHandlers.developmentErrors);
}

// production error handler
app.use(errorHandlers.productionErrors);

module.exports = app;
```

Here is the index.js file I have to handle all of my routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I run `npm start` on the command line, here is what I get:

```
> summer_breeze@1.0.0 start /Users/**********/Repos/Summer_Breeze
> nodemon ./start.js

[nodemon] 1.14.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node ./start.js`
Express running → PORT 7777
```

Which is great. This is running as I had expected. But when I go to localhost:7777/ in a web browser, It pulls up my index.html page inside of my public folder and when I pull up the console in dev tools there is nothing. It's as if it is completely ignoring the routes I had created.

Why would this be? The only route I have is only supposed to console log 'Hello World!'. I assumed that I would have to run
 `router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('public/index.html');
});` for it to be loading my index.html file.

Why would it be pulling my index.html file? Is there a default route that serves my static files if there are issues finding my index.js file? I have even attempted to delete all routes from my index.js file and it still seems to load my index.html file.

Could anyone give me a little more insight into what is going on? Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to swap `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` and `app.use('/', routes);`

Comment: Swap them as in change the order?

Comment: Yes. First issue `app.use('/'....)`, then `app.use(express.static(...))`

Comment: This worked! Do you mind briefly explaining why that works? I'm still curious as to why it was pulling my index.html file out of my public folder...

Comment: To cut long story short when you applied `app.use(express.static(...))` then "express" registered express.static as route for '/' . Then you added your own route for '/', but _after_  static. Indeed when you requested '/' from your server then static processed this request and returned 'index.html'.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: yoo this saved me thanks!

Answer (score 0):

res.send actually is sending a response with the string your passing. Comment out res.send and use console.log("hello world"), then you will see it in your console on your server, since its server side. Not on chrome dev tools.

Comment: Even after removing this, it still does not work and does not show up in the console....I'm more confused as to why my index.html file is showing up at all rather than the route function working or not.

Comment: Im trying to help you understand the first part of your question. You expected console.log to show up in dev tools. Thats not correct.